In the era where Mad Men is set, are smoke alarms not triggered by cigarette smoke?

From this picture from Episode 2 Season 1 of Mad Men, I have circled two cigarettes in red and three smoke alarms in black on the ceiling.
I am assuming they are smoke alarms. If they are, why are they not triggered by smoke coming from cigarettes in the office?

Were smoke detectors even a thing back then? I live in Germany, and we are a lot more regulation-happy than the US, but even here, smoke detectors only became mandatory in residences in all 16 States a year ago. (In some States, they have been mandatory for new buildings and renovations for 10 years, but the last grandfather clause ran out in Saxonia on New Year's Eve 2023.) In offices, they are still not mandatory, except in one State. They didn't even become affordable until the 1970s.

Why would there be smoke alarms that could be triggered by cigarette smoke in an era where tons of people smoked in an office? Also, cigarette smoke setting off smoke alarms is a rare event.

I very much doubt those are meant to be smoke detectors. Small, commercially viable smoke detectors didn’t become available until the early 1970s

In that era, if that's how they worked they'd have been a non-starter as a product.

I believe these things are lights. You see them dotted around the ceiling.

Even today that would be an unusual density of smoke detectors, 3 visible in one part of a room. Recessed sprinklers seems much more likely

@Valorum Emergency lights. They're over the lanes between the desks, and look like they have glass diffusers.

@MarkMorganLloyd - I think these are employed as set lights, for lighting up different parts of the set when they're filming closer to one of the desks. For example, in this image they're not filming near to the door so the overhead lights are off; https://cdn.ultraswank.net/uploads/HT_mad_men_set_conference_room_jef_140409_3x2_1600-1000x666.jpg

When I started work in the early 1980's for the Canadian Federal government (somewhat known for regulation) my desk (all desks) sported a visitor's ashtray big amber dark glass probably bullet proof. When you left some meeting rooms a trail of smoke would waft out with you. The ceiling might not sport a smoke fog layer like many afterwork bars did as you left when the evening traffic cleared out.

Are they possibly mood music speakers, a PA, or a Tannoy ?

@JörgWMittag The US is more strict about smoke detectors and fire safety in general. Residential smoke detectors became required on every floor in 1976 (NFPA-72). In 1993, smoke detectors were mandated in every sleeping room, and in 2007, they became mandated directly outside every sleeping room and interconnected. California mandated single-family homes have sprinklers in 2010.

They probably aren't smoke alarms.  That seems like way more smoke alarms than you would need, especially with that spacing.
I think it's more likely that they are concealed/recessed sprinkler heads.  When they are exposed to enough heat, a solder joint will melt/break and the sprinkler head will drop down and begin spraying water.
In a time when everyone was smoking inside, this would be pretty practical for fighting real fires while not giving false alarms all the time from cigarette smoke.
Also, just looking around my office, the spacing between heads is very similar (ours have six 2'x2' tiles between each head, this picture seems to show five between each).

OT: The gym where I swim has twelve sprinkler heads over the swimming pool.  In case, you know, the pool catches fire I guess.

@CrashGordon - pool covers are often made of flammable materials

Was the pool installed from the building's initial construction or did the gym do a major renovation at lease and have the pool added ex post? More likely indoor structures may require so many sprinklers per x square feet whether or what is present beneath.

The rosettes are held shut by solder, that generally melts around 60, 70, or 120 degrees C.   They take ages to start spraying water and the building is normally well alight before they trigger.   Cigarette do not release that much heat else they'd burn faster.

@Criggie in a modern system there are additionally high-pressure pumps triggered by the fire alarm system - when they're tested they make an awful racket - but hat alone isn't enough to release the water.  There are valves as you say, and some still use an alloy like Fields metal (others use a glass bulb to hold them shut, that breaks when the contents expands).  But in any case you'd need to hold a flame or other heat source up to them directly to trigger them - even a hairdryer needs to be incapable of doing it accidentally

(would be an edit but waited too long) The gym is in a bespoke building; the pool area has always been a pool, and there's never been a pool cover.  And even if there was a pool cover, what would it be resting on?  Maybe the sprinklers are there in case the pool is ever drained.

@CrashGordon The sprinklers may be pointed up to protect the roof structure in a fire, important because you have a large structure without supports in the middle, and that's where hot gases are going to accumulate.

Not smoke alarms
According to this link from the Wikipedia entry, industrial smoke detectors were first on sale for commercial buildings in 1968.  Domestic smoke alarms took longer to arrive, because they needed to be made more cost-effective.
Since the series is set from 1960 to 1970, and this episode is from season 1, these cannot be smoke detectors.
Fire detection alarms (often based on melting wax plugs, a simple but effective method which is still widely used today) have been available for much longer, of course. These could be what are depicted here. They are clearly not sprinklers, because sprinklers need to spray over a wider area.
More likely though, they could simply be air-con return vents. Air would be drawn in through those smaller vents, and circulated around the room through the larger directional vents. For an office where these simply carry out air circulation without cooling, there is no need to have these separated.

Recessed sprinklers stay in the ceiling until heat melts/weakens something holding them up, then they drop down to look like regular sprinklers that give good coverage.  Those seem like weird places for air return too.  One is right next to a supply, it would just be dumping supply air right back out of the room.  They look quite small for return vents too.
